# Remove background to see underlying view controller when using popover

Tags: ios, uimodalpresentationstyle

If you would like to present a view controller modally yet continue to see the underlying view controller, you can change the `UIModalPresentationStyle` to Over Full Screen, then set the view's `backgroundColor` to `clearColor`, or a color with a lowered alpha value. The default Full Screen presentation causes the underlying controller to disappear, so you'll see black underneath unless you use Over Full Screen or Over Current Context.

Now I would like to instead use the adaptive Popover presentation style, which will cause the view controller to be presented full screen on the iPhone in portrait or in a form sheet if run on iPhone 6 Plus in landscape. But I want to preserve the "over full screen" style - I want to be able to see the underlying view controller through the new view controller. How can that be accomplished, when by default it disappears therefore is black underneath?